# How to merge some keys into *args and then call another method with those args?

Tags: ruby

I have the following method:

```
def item(*args, &block)
  options = args.extract_options!
  options.reverse_update({
    brand: false,
    icon: false,
  })
  # Do some stuff
end
```

And this method:

```
def brand(*args, &block)
  options = args.extract_options!
  options[:brand] = true

  self.item(???, &block) # How does this call have to look?
end
```

The 2nd last line is of interest. I want to call the `item` with exact the same parameters like the `brand` method was called (except I added another parameter, `brand`).

Comment: It's easy. I assume that `extract_options` takes an array and returns a hash. You just have to provide a method that does the opposite.

Comment: Joshua, 1) the same doubt I had in your previous question: apart from the options hash, what's in `args`? 2) as I said using this kind of signature imho is not advisable (except for excepcional cases).

Comment: @tokland, I'm experimenting at the moment with signatures like they are seen in Rails a lot. I thank you for your opinion and concerns, I will keep them in mind, but at the moment this seems for me a good way to go.

Comment: @Joshua: Ok. Yeah, Rails use this a lot. But just out of curiosity, what's in `args` apart from the options hash? not top secret I guess :-) The problems with this kind of signature, well, you are already experiencing them: it requires some boilerplate to manage. This would be a one-liner with "normal" signatures.

Comment: @tokland: Take a look at the [gist](https://gist.github.com/3721506). I want to support different ways that the method can be called: with 2 or 3 params (of which the last one is the options hash), with a block or without a block. I'm happy to hear your opinion.

Comment: @Joshua: thanks. I see, it's like link_to in Rails, the caption may be an argument or a block so the arguments size is variable. More comments on the gist.

Comment: @tokland: Thanks for your comments. I learned Ruby through Rails, so I like this approach, but I see that it can lead to confusion and dirty code. Have a nice weekends and thanks again for your good intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd write:

```
def brand(*args, &block)
  options = args.extract_options!
  options[:brand] = true

  self.item(*(args+[options]), &block)
end
```